# javascript: class inheritance method call

Tags: javascript

I am new to JS, I am particularly confused by following code:

```js
class One{
    constructor(num){
        this.num = num;
    }

    add(){
        this.num += 1;
    }

    showInfo(){
        this.add();
        console.log(`The result is ${this.num}`);
    }
}

class Ten extends One{
    constructor(num){
        super(num);
    }

    add(){
        this.num += 10;
    }
}

let t = new Ten(1);
t.showInfo();
// The result is 11
```

I thought the result should be 2, because `showInfo` is executed in `One` so `add` should be executed in `One` as well, furthermore, `showInfo` is only defined in `One`, but why is `One.showInfo` calling `Ten.add` instead of `One.add`?

I will be so glad if someone offer some explanation.

Comment: Are you aware of how polymorphism works?

Comment: Try `console.log(this)` in your `showInfo` - you'd not be surprised anymore.

Comment: For any `Ten` instance `Ten`'s prototypal `add` method [shadows](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain#Inheritance_with_the_prototype_chain) the one implemented by `One`. If one wants to support the latter for any `Ten` instance one needs to implement another (prototypal) method which does a [`super`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#Super_class_calls_with_super) delegation ... e.g. `addOne() { return super.add(); }`. Then one can do e.g. `const t = new Ten(1); t.add() /* 11 */; t.addOne() /* 12 */;`

Answer (score 1):

The showInfo () is inherited by the Ten class and it is executed on the Ten class calling the add () of the Ten class;
Yielding 11;

To return 2 add () implementation in Ten Class should call super.add() instead

Answer (score 0):

```
add(){
        return super.add();
    }
```

Go through the below :)

https://javascript.info/class-inheritance